# Invalid Firebase Database path: 1.0. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am calling values from my database to use in an android MP like chart, it was originally working but for some reason no longer is may be because the line chart needs to use float values so changed the data in the database to float values.

Here is my code for calling the data:

```
DatabaseReference databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Carbonfootprint").child(userid).child(String.valueOf(total));
            databaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final LineChartresult linechats = dataSnapshot.getValue(LineChartresult.class);
                    score = linechats.getCarbonfootprint();

                    dataVals.add(new Entry(total, score));
                    total++;
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

have checked by database here is the Json format

```
{
  "Carbonfootprint" : {
    "yV3msXDJxDXFo5gchxgbk7OjLHi2" : [ null, {
      "carbonfootprint" : 13.300000190734863
    }, {
      "carbonfootprint" : 12.699999809265137
    }, {
      "carbonfootprint" : 12.100000381469727
    }, {
      "carbonfootprint" : 9.100000381469727
    } ]
  },
```

Unsure as to why it says null ? as on my database it looks like this: screenshot attached..
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TFJL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `total` is a floating point number, then `String.valueOf(total)` will certainly contain a ".".  The error message is telling you that "." is not a valid character to use in a path.

It seems also that you're not approaching the query correctly from the perspective of your data.  It seems like you would want to query the entire node called "Carbonfootprint/yV3msXDJxDXFo5gchxgbk7OjLHi2", and look through the array for the data you need.